# Rewriting remote git branch without force push or delete permissions

Tags: git, azure-devops

I wrote a first draft of a C# .NET core program as proof of concept, which was uploaded as both master and dev branches. Unfortunately, I forgot to use a .gitignore file and it uploaded all of the debug and release build files.

Since then I've rewritten the whole program to work much more efficiently, and I'd like to rebase/replace the entire master/dev branch with that. We're using DevOps, but I've always used TFS, and I don't understand why git "refuses" to push my branch. It wants me to pull down all of the obsolete remote dev work, then doesn't merge them when I do. Also tried deleting every file in the remote dev branch, so it is now empty on the DevOps site. The admin won't give me force push and branch deletion permissions, probably because I'm new to the commands.

How would I rewrite the dev and master branches with my local code?

Pushing my code (I am on dev branch and have already done "git add ." and "git commit -m "Comment"):

```
git push -f origin dev
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To [remote repository]
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (TF401027: You need the Git 'ForcePush' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'a7cf8844-7bf6-48af-88cc-3063f00ff148\[my credentials]', scope 'branch'.)
```

```
$ git pull origin dev
From [remote repository]
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

From a fresh clone:

```
git clone [remote repository]
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 407 objects to send. (316 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (407/407), 6.47 MiB | 332.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (61/61), done.

$ cd MyProject

$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'

$ git pull origin dev
From [remote repository]
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the question? You cannot push a rewritten history without using some kind of `force`, and that's that. So what exactly have you done, and what is it that you want to do? Show actual git commands and what git replied to you.

Comment: Well, the problem "refusing to merge unrelated histories" is easily solved, just say `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: @matt that was the catalyst for a workaround, thanks for the help.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT All of my questions and answers get downvoted. Apparently I'm just an idiot, so I don't think it'll be beneficial to anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Successfully rewrote the remote branch without doing a force push through the following:

1. Backup local dev repo.
2. Recreate the remote repo locally:

```
git clone [remote repository]

$ cd MyProject

$ git checkout -b dev

$ git pull origin dev --allow-unrelated-histories
```

3. Replace new dev repo files with local file backup.
4. Commit changes and push again:

```
$ git add .

$ git commit -m "Comments"

$ git push origin dev
```

Comment: Note that this did not rewrite anything.

Answer (score 1):

Git (actually the server) does not allow that.

Git rejects all pushes that don't just add commits to branches.

If you want to rewrite history, you need to force push.

If you rewrite and force push something and there is work based of it, those people need to fix it on their machine too as they have non-rewritten version.

I also recommend you to use `--force-with-lease` instead of a normal force push as it rejects if the remote contains work you don't know of.

Comment: You were more right the first time: "Git does not allow that". What's running on the server is exactly the same thing (git) that is running on the local computer. We can talk about "our" git and "their" git, or "local" git and "remote" git, but what forbids pushing here is just plain old git. — Also, note that git's concern when it rejects a push is not that it "doesn't just add commits to branches", its concern is that no existing referenced commit should be permitted to become unreferenced.

Comment: I wanted to say that the server-side is the problem. I know that this is how git works.